# Compiling with deleted functions fails with uclibc

Tags: c++, gcc, glibc, uclibc

I have a project I am porting from glibc to uclibc, and ran into this oddity.

```
gcc --std=c++11 Foo.cpp -o Foo-glibc
x86_64-linux-uclibc-gcc --std=c++11 Foo.cpp -o Foo-uclibc

// Compiles under glibc and uclibc
class Foo {
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(const Foo& arg) = delete;
  ~Foo() = default;
};

// Only compiles under glibc
class Foo {
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(const Foo& arg);
  ~Foo() = default;
};
Foo::Foo(const Foo& arg) = delete; // uclibc - Error: deleted definition of 'Foo::Foo(const Foo&)'
```

Why does this error occur? Is this expected behavior? Nothing I've read suggests that uclibc shouldn't be able to handle this.

Comment: Ulibc is a library as such and doesn't have anything to do with the compiler (not with the compilation at least). Are you sure your gccs are the same version? (run `gcc --version` and `x86_64-linux-uclibc-gcc  --version`

Comment: `gcc --version` yields 4.8.5 and `x86_64-linux-uclibc-gcc --version` yields 7.3.0. So this is most likely tied to the version difference between compilers, though I'm not sure why a newer compiler would remove this function.

Comment: it was presumably a bug that it worked in the first place, it makes no sense to declare a constructor in the class declaration then delete it out of line. How would a consumer of the class know that the constructor is deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely a bug in older gcc versions.

In 4.8.5 it [worked](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Brg9wDciSR1JpUGT), but in 5.1.0 it [doesn't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hhZkq1JvVvWZae01).

To quote Alan Birtles

> [I]t makes no sense to declare a constructor in the class declaration[,] then delete it out of line. How would a consumer of the class know that the constructor is deleted?

Comment: Turns out it is. I should start developing with some newer compilers then! Thanks!